# StaleStateException when saving a entity deleted by other session (concurrency)

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency

I´m using NHibernate to data access Layer.
I have an entity in memory previously loaded, and Im making changes in order to save after on database. The problem comes when my application is running in some machines at the same time, and other user has deleted from database the same object that I have in memory and I want to save. When I try save the changes or delete this entity, a StaleStateException in fired.

I check if an entity exists on database calling `session.Get<T>` of this way (it´s get a null succesfully):

```
using (var session = NHibernateSessionHelper.OpenSession())
{
   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
       var entity = session.Get<T>(persistObject.Id);
       return entity == null ? false : true;
   }
}
```

The problem comes when I can´t differentiate between when the entity has been deleted by other session/user (therefore my entity in memory is obsolete) or the entity has been recently created and is able to save.
I think that the unique solution is implement a mechanism to check if the entity has already been saved or loaded from database, in order to discard the entity or save when proceed.

Is there a way to check this behaviour by using nhibernate? Im tried with `session.Refresh() and session.Get<T>` but I still without know if the object is new and ready to save or obsolete.

Help very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situaltion you have is a tipical error handling one. Because a user have dicided to delete an object in your database and an other user want save a change to the same object you can't say what the right state should be. The user is the one who should dicide what to do with situation. You can make your error handling smarter by giving him some chooses. For situations where you have multiple users which write to the same object you should also implement a meganism like optimistic locking to prevent an other user to override a change which he did not see. If you have many of these situation you should think about redesign your db/object structure to edit less data at once or rethink the work/processes your users do with the system.

Comment: Yes, I´m agree with you(is my initial opinion) but i didn´t know if is there any mechanism in NHibernate to get if an entity is obsolete or not. I have a work around, creating a boolean property in the entity indicating if has been created by the user(creating new elements) or filled by Nhibernate.